# Showing an Android view from a dynamically loaded assembly in Xamarin MvvmCross

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am writing a plugin manager for my android app written in Xamarin with MvvmCross.

I am loading the assembly just fine, i can enumerate all types (ViewModels, Views, ...). For the view type finding, i implemented a custom `IMvxViewFinder` that i registered during Setup

```
protected override IMvxAndroidViewsContainer CreateViewsContainer(Context applicationContext)
{
    var androidViewsContainer = base.CreateViewsContainer(applicationContext);
    var viewsContainer = androidViewsContainer as IMvxViewsContainer;
    if (viewsContainer != null)
    {
        viewsContainer.AddSecondary(new PluginViewFinder());
    }

    return androidViewsContainer;
}
```

I am able to match the external viewmodel to the external view type. All functions are hit and the correct views are returned. But I still get a class not found exception

```
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5996393b23f6d276fda35c7846aecfb34.FirstView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/test.droid-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/test.droid-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00064] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:195 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x0001d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:203 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:494 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (System.Type type) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:434 
  --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5996393b23f6d276fda35c7846aecfb34.FirstView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/test.droid-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/test.droid-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56) ...
```

So, it is trying to find the view inside `/data/app/test.droid-1/base.apk` - that's the main project, that loaded the assembly - so, for sure, the class is not in there.

Anybody a hint what i have to do for that?

Comment: Is the View in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: no, but none of my views are.

Comment: That is obviously your problem, if they aren't in the resulting AndroidManifest after build (you can check in the obj/Android folder) then Android won't be able to navigate to that Activity.

Comment: You also need to add the Name like this: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/master/Samples/Example.Droid/Activities/MainActivity.cs#L25

Comment: Or when using fragments, do a register: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/master/Samples/Example.Droid/Fragments/ExampleRecyclerViewFragment.cs#L19

Comment: but all other activities and fragments work (there are not in my manifest either), it's just the once that come from this extended plugin that i load during runtime using `Assembly.Load`

Comment: The others get populated in the manifest on build time and actually ARE in the resulting AndroidManifest. If the Activity you are trying to launch from that external library is not in the resulting AndroidManifest, then you wont be able to launch it. End of story. Add it or suffer.